# trying to install mongo but getting errors

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, mongodb

I am following mongo site (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/ ) to install mongo on my centos 5.1o

I am getting following errors

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www8.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirrors.tummy.com
 * epel: mirror.compevo.com
 * extras: mirror.raystedman.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
atomic                                                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                                          | 1.1 kB     00:00     
c5-testing                                                                    | 1.9 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org.i686 0:2.6.1-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.i686 0:2.6.1-1 set to be updated
---> Package mongodb-org-server.i686 0:2.6.1-1 set to be updated
---> Package mongodb-org-shell.i686 0:2.6.1-1 set to be updated
---> Package mongodb-org-tools.i686 0:2.6.1-1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch              Version                Repository            Size
=====================================================================================================
Installing:
 mongodb-org                     i686              2.6.1-1                mongodb              4.6 k
Installing for dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos              i686              2.6.1-1                mongodb              6.7 M
 mongodb-org-server              i686              2.6.1-1                mongodb              8.9 M
 mongodb-org-shell               i686              2.6.1-1                mongodb              4.2 M
 mongodb-org-tools               i686              2.6.1-1                mongodb               88 M

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 108 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
mongo-10gen-server conflicts with mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-1.i686
mongo-10gen-tools conflicts with mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-1.i686
mongo-10gen-shell conflicts with mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-1.i686
mongo-10gen-mongos conflicts with mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-1.i686
mongo-10gen conflicts with mongodb-org-2.6.1-1.i686
Complete!
(1, [u'Please report this error in http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug'])
```

What can I do to fix these and get mongo going

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your package conflict with older version of mongodb. Package mongo-10gen is mongodb 2.4 (references [here](http://www.mongodb.com/subscription/downloads)). To resolve that, just uninstall the conflicting packages

```
sudo yum remove mongo-10gen-server mongo-10gen-tools mongo-10gen-shell mongo-10gen-mongos mongo-10gen
```

Then install again mongodb

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```